# Add a variable of type Thread to a variable of type Observable <{[key: string]: Thread}>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Here is how I boot my variable threads:

```
threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;
```

And this is how I initialize my variable threads :

```
this.threads = messageService.messages
  .map((messages: Message[]) => {
    const threads: { [key: string]: Thread } = {};
    messages.map((message: Message) => {
      threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id] ||
        message.thread;

      const messagesThread: Thread = threads[message.thread.id];
      if (!messagesThread.lastMessage ||
        messagesThread.lastMessage.date < message.date) {
        messagesThread.lastMessage = message;
      }
    });
    return threads;
  });
```

I want to add a variable newThread to the variable threads :

```
const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, objmessage.participants);
```

I tried this:

```
threads = Observable.of([newThread]);
```

Or this :

```
this.threads.subscribe((thread: Thread) => {
   threads.next(newThread);
});
```

But It dosen't work. However the type is not the right one.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDIT :

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

When I change my thread variable to be BehaviorSubject:

```
threads: BehaviorSubject<{[key: string]: Thread }> = BehaviorSubject.create();
```

I modify this initialization :

```
this.messageService.messages.map((messages: Message[]) => {
  const threads: { [key: string]: Thread } = {};
  messages.map((message: Message) => {
    threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id] ||
      message.thread;

    const messagesThread: Thread = threads[message.thread.id];
    if (!messagesThread.lastMessage ||
      messagesThread.lastMessage.date < message.date) {
      messagesThread.lastMessage = message;
    }
  });
  return threads;
}).subscribe(threads => {
  this.threads.next(threads);
});
```

And I put this :

```
addThread(newThread: Thread): void {
  this.threadService.newThreads.push(newThread);
  this.threadService.newThreadsId.push(newThread.id);

this.threadService.orderedThreads.next(this.threadService.newThreads);

let threads = this.threadService.threads.value;
this.threadService.threads.next(threads);
}
```

And I have this error :

```
Cannot set property 'flo' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'tRev' of undefined
```

'flo' it's l'id of my Thread :

```
this.addNewMessageNewThread({
  "id": "flo",
  "author": "Flo Peron",
  "body": "COUUUUCOU",
  "title": "Groupe 158"
});
```

Comment: [Thread] is a type. Observable.of() expects a sequence that can be turned into a observable

Comment: @Mitta
I changed that : threads = Observable.of([newThread]);

But it does not work either. Is it possible to add 'newThread' to 'threads'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a subject and not an observable.  Specifically, you probably want a behavior subject since you want to modify the current value.

```
threads: BehaviorSubject<{[key: string]: Thread}>;

messageService.messages.map(...).subscribe(threads => {
  this.threads.next(threads);
});

addThread(key: string, thread: Thread) {
  let threads = this.threads.value;
  threads[key] = thread;
  this.threads.next(threads);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this one marks me a mistake for the line : `this.threads.next(threads);`

Error : `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`

I do not understand why ..

Comment: I published my post. Can you look please, I do not see how to do with a variable of type BehaviorSubject? ..